# How linear classification for images equivalent to template matching?

Tags: image, computer-vision, multilabel-classification

In the CS231n course of Stanford (http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#loss), we train a linear classifier on images from CIFAR-10, and when plotting the weight matrix for each class, we get an image that resembles the class predicted. How is that a consequence of the training process? What is the mathematical reason behind it ?

Linear classifier: f(x, W, b) = W*x + b
input x is a flattened image
each row of W can be reconstructed to become an image